# Find the three roots of the equation $\left(z+1\right)^3=-1$

Tags: complex-numbers

> Give your answers in the form $x+ iy$, where $x\in \mathbb{R}\:and\:y\in \mathbb{R}$.

I suspect I'll have to use de Moivre's theorem to solve this, but I don't know how to factor in the $+1$, because increasing the real part of a complex number by one doesn't necessarily increase its modulus by one.
I know that one of the roots will be $-2$, by inspection, but that's about it.

Comment: Two ways: use that $-2$ is a root hence $$(z+1)^3+1=(z+2)(z^2+uz+v)$$ for some complex $(u,v)$, identify $(u,v)$, solve $z^2+uz+v=0$, rejoice.

Comment: Or use the fact that the three third roots of $-1$ are $-1$, $-j$ and $-j^2$, where $$j=e^{2i\pi/3}=-\frac12+i\frac{\sqrt3}2$$ hence $z=-1-1$ or $z=-1-j$ or $z=-1-j^2$.

Comment: $(z+1)^3=z^3+3z^2+3z+1$ so you could solve the cubic: $z^3+3z^2+3z+2=0$

Comment: also if you know that one of the roots is $z=-2$ then you can factor out $(z+2)$ and use the quadratic formula can't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider instead 
$$c^3 = -1$$
where $c = z + 1$. Denoting in geometric form $c = re^{i\theta}$ and $-1 = e^{i \pi}$, we get
$$r^3 e^{i3\theta} = e^{i\pi + 2k\pi}, \qquad k \in \lbrace 0,1,2 \rbrace$$ 
We get $r = 1$ and three different angles 
\begin{align}
\theta_1 &= \frac{\pi}{3} =  \\
\theta_2 &= \frac{\pi}{3} + \frac{2\pi}{3} = \pi\\
\theta_3 &= \frac{\pi}{3} + \frac{4\pi}{3} = \frac{5\pi}{3}\\
\end{align}
So we get $c_1 = e^{i\frac{\pi}{3}}$, $c_2 = e^{i\pi}$ and $c_3 = e^{i\frac{5\pi}{3}}$. The corresponding roots are
\begin{align}
z_1 &= -1 + e^{i\frac{\pi}{3}} = (-1 + \cos(\frac{\pi}{3})) + i\sin(\frac{\pi}{3})  \\
z_2 &= -1 + e^{i\pi} = (-1 + \cos(\pi)) + i\sin(\pi)\\
z_3 &= -1 + e^{i\frac{5\pi}{3}}= (-1 + \cos(\frac{5\pi}{3})) + i\sin(\frac{5\pi}{3})\\
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Since you know that $z=-2$ is one of the roots, then it makes sense to expand the left hand side, move the $-1$ over from the right, and factor the resulting cubic:

$$(z+1)^3=-1\iff z^3+3z^2+3z+1=-1\iff z^3+3z^2+3z+2=0\iff(z+2)(z^2+z+1)=0$$

so the other two roots are the roots of the quadratic,

$$z={-1\pm\sqrt{1-4}\over2}={-1\pm\sqrt{-3}\over2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Try Solving $y^3 = -1$ to get $y = - e^{2 k \pi /3}$ for $k\in\lbrace 0,1,2 \rbrace$ and then find the three points such that $z = y-1$ for the three values of $y$